# Adjoint Isomorphisms and Enveloping Algebra

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$.
I am studying the group homomorphisms between $A$-bimodules $DA$ and $A$, where $D=\operatorname{Hom}_k(-,k)$.

Suppose $\operatorname{Hom}_{A-A} (DA,A)=0$.

I know that the category of $A$-bimodules is equivalent to the category of left (right) $A^e$-modules, where $A^e = A \otimes_k A^{op}$ is called of the enveloping algebra: if $M$ is an $A$-bimodule, we define a left (right) $A^e$-structure in the following way
$$
(a \otimes b)m=amb \quad (m(a \otimes b) = bma).
$$

Therefore, we have $\operatorname{Hom}_{A-A} (DA,A) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{A^e} (DA,A) = 0$.

Now, my question...
I don't know what is wrong with my argument using Adjoint Isomorphism:
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{A^e} (DA \otimes_k DA \otimes_k DA ,A) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{k} (DA \otimes_k DA,\operatorname{Hom}_{A^e} (DA,A)) = 0
$$

I know it's wrong because using the isomorphism
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{A^e} (DA \otimes_k DA \otimes_k DA ,A) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{k} (DA ,A) \neq 0
$$
given by $f \to \tilde{f}$, with $\tilde{f}(x)=f(1 \otimes x \otimes1)$.

Thank you very much for your help and comments.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $\bar{f}$. How are you regarding $1\otimes x\otimes1$ as an element of $DA\otimes_kDA\otimes_kDA$? $1$ is not an element of $DA$.

Comment: Maybe, my fault is this adaptation. I am studying this article http://www.revistas.usp.br/resenhasimeusp/article/view/75034
This work explains this isomorphism
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{A^e} (A \otimes_k A \otimes_k A ,M) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{k} (A ,M) 
$$
where $M$ be an $A$-bimodule.
I was wrong to switch $A$ for $DA$.